# Rotation problemo with the pen on x230 tablet and an external screen?

Tags: windows-7, external-display, pen, tablet-pc

I have a funny problem. Normally when I have the screen rotated 180 on the laptop as I'm writing on it everything works just fine. But if I connect an external monitor that is oriented "normal", with the laptop at 180 rotated the pen and finger touch response is completely reversed. I go right, it goes left... and it matches dead center in the screen. It works if I rotate the external screen by 180, on the head. Not very practical.

To sum it up: When connected to an external monitor with laptop screen rotated 180 degrees and the external at normal the pen and touch motions are reversed. I couldn't calibrate the pen to work this way either. Because I would click the opposite diagonal corner.

Comment: [Here's a related thread for x220](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-Tablet-ThinkPad-Laptops/Pen-input-does-not-rotate-with-screen/td-p/759693), can you try if that works for you?

Comment: Actually, I just tried to use the "extended screen" mode instead of cloning. And it works now.